# Select primary monitor at boot

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors

I have connected a secondary monitor on my geforce 560ti vga connector, the main monitor has always been connected to the DVI port. The problem is that now the monitor on the VGA port is being treated as primary. I can of couse change this on the OS level, but I'd like to keep my DVI port monitor as primary even at PC boot (POST, BIOS settings and grub). How can I do this?